# Android Studio: Set dropped TextView to whatever was dragged

Tags: java, android, android-studio, drag-and-drop

I am implementing a Drag and Drop interface with 6 Drag TextViews and 6 Drop TextViews.
Any 1 of 6 Drag views can be dropped onto any 1 of 6 Drop views.

An example would be if tvNum1=13, tvNum2=16, tvNum3=9, then I can drop any one of them onto tvSTR, tvDEX, or tvINT and set the respective Drop text to whatever was dragged. So if tvNum2 was dragged onto tvSTR, then tvSTR should show 16. Or let's say that instead you decided to drag tvNum3 onto tvSTR, then tvSTR should show 9. Each Drag view can only be used once.

Here's my current code. I can't find a way to make it so that the text of whatever was dragged is the text of the Drop view. I can only make (a 1-to-1 correlation) it so that if tvNum1 was dragged onto tvSTR, then tvSTR=13. Or if tvNum2 was dragged onto tvDEX, then tvDEX=16.

```
public class setCharacterRolls extends AppCompatActivity
{
    // Variable declarations
    private TextView tvNum1, tvNum2, tvNum3, tvNum4, tvNum5, tvNum6;
    private TextView tvSTR, tvDEX, tvINT, tvWIS, tvCHA, tvCON;
    String roll1, roll2, roll3, roll4, roll5, roll6;
    // String roll1Num, roll2Num, roll3Num, roll4Num, roll5Num, roll6Num;
    private Button bSubmit;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_character_rolls);

        // Get the previous intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        // Save the rolls from the previous screen onto a String to use later.
        roll1 = intent.getStringExtra("roll1");
        roll2 = intent.getStringExtra("roll2");
        roll3 = intent.getStringExtra("roll3");
        roll4 = intent.getStringExtra("roll4");
        roll5 = intent.getStringExtra("roll5");
        roll6 = intent.getStringExtra("roll6");

        // Get TextView id's
        tvNum1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tDrag1);
        tvNum2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tDrag2);
        tvNum3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tDrag3);
        tvNum4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tDrag4);
        tvNum5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tDrag5);
        tvNum6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tDrag6);

        tvSTR = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSTR);
        tvDEX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDEX);
        tvINT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvINT);
        tvWIS = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvWIS);
        tvCHA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCHA);
        tvCON = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCON);

        // Set TextView to the roll numbers
        tvNum1.setText(roll1);
        tvNum2.setText(roll2);
        tvNum3.setText(roll3);
        tvNum4.setText(roll4);
        tvNum5.setText(roll5);
        tvNum6.setText(roll6);

        // Set TextView to be draggable
        tvNum1.setOnTouchListener(onTouch);
        tvNum2.setOnTouchListener(onTouch);
        tvNum3.setOnTouchListener(onTouch);
        tvNum4.setOnTouchListener(onTouch);
        tvNum5.setOnTouchListener(onTouch);
        tvNum6.setOnTouchListener(onTouch);

        // Targets to be dropped on
        tvSTR.setOnDragListener(dragListener);
        tvDEX.setOnDragListener(dragListener);
        tvINT.setOnDragListener(dragListener);
        tvWIS.setOnDragListener(dragListener);
        tvCHA.setOnDragListener(dragListener);
        tvCON.setOnDragListener(dragListener);


    }

    View.OnTouchListener onTouch = new View.OnTouchListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent mEvent)
        {
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuild = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
            v.startDrag(data, shadowBuild, v, 0);
            return true;
        }
    };


    View.OnDragListener dragListener = new View.OnDragListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event)
        {
            int dragEvent = event.getAction();

            switch(dragEvent)
            {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    final View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                    switch(view.getId())
                    {
                        // This is where I have the 1-to-1 correlation.
                        // I want to be able to drag any draggable texview and set it to whatever it was dropped on.
                        case R.id.tDrag1:
                            tvSTR.setText(roll1);
                            break;
                        case R.id.tDrag2:
                            tvDEX.setText(roll2); 
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;

            }

            return true;
        }
    };
}
```